# What font is being used on the Mudd Island Memphis sign?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, signage

I have tried looking for this font but because there is already a font type named Memphis it keeps clogging my google results.  Can anyone tell me what font is being used on the sign in this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a custom design, the S vertices and stroke are very different from the other characters.

The P shape is a fairly common design in Nouveau and Deco style fonts.

---

Similar font: [Nouveau To Go JNL](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jnlevine/nouveau-to-go/regular/)

[image]

Comment: That is a good find, they do share many similarities. I dont know much about fonts, but I feel like the S looks very strange compared the other letters, maybe its the because its the only character that widens or maybe its the sharp top of the S.  Regardless thank you for your quick reply!